# ImageView NullPointer Error

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I have this error : **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference**

I have followed the step to put `ImageView` in an activity. How does the error happen and how to fix it? Noted that in hadis_layout, I use `RecylerView`. Thanks

1. My ImageView

   ```
   <ImageView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:id="@+id/hadisView"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_weight="0.36"
   android:contentDescription="Hadis"
   android:src="@drawable/hadith01arabic"/>
   ```
2. My Activity

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.hadis_layout);

       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hadisView);
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hadith01arabic);

   }
   ```

Comment: `imageView` is null because `findViewById` is returning null, probably because it cannot find the view with the `Id` specified.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try checking what the value of `R.id.hadisView` is before calling `setImageResource`? Just to get more information about the problem.

Comment: 1. Double check that you are loading the correct layout file. 2. Do a clean build of your project.

Comment: Can you please post you complete code of xml and java code.

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

- You cannot just change your `recycleview` Image resource from
  `activity`. to do that you have to make changes to your overwritten 
  `onBindViewHolder` function at the `RecycleViewAdapter` class. add

  `ViewHolderObject.imgResourceIdName.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);`

  to `onBindViewHolder` function in `RecycleViewAdapter` class with relevant id of the `itemView` to
  be changed. (here `imgResourceIdName` is in the recycleView **single_rv_item.xml** resource file.)

---

The above error occurs when you try to set an image resource to an       `ImageView` which isn't in the `resouce_layout.xml` file. that means     even though you set your image resource by

`imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hadith01arabic);`
  the    object of `imageView` is **null**.

by doing

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hadisView);`

you have just initialize an    ***null***    `imageView` object variable which of **ImageView** data type. because    `findViewById(R.id.hadisView)` does not points to    any resource. check whether the `hadisView` named **imageView** resource presents in    the relevant **resource.xml** file first.